# Couldn't start/open an activity when expandable listview item/child clicked and how to implement Toast here

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-emulator

I created expandable listview in a fragment and it's works fine. However I want to start an activity when expandable listview child item clicked. I've looked for hours trying to find a solution to this but I couldn't find it. Someone please provide code for this problem.

```
import android.R.color;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

        // This is a listfragment class
        public class Categories extends Fragment {

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories, null);
                ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
                elv.setAdapter(new SavedTabsListAdapter());
                return v;
            }

            public class SavedTabsListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

                private String[] groups = { "Men", "Women"};

                private String[][] children = {
                    { "Men's accessories", "Men's trousers"},
                    { "Dresses", "Women's trousers"}
                };

                @Override
                public int getGroupCount() {
                    return groups.length;
                }

                @Override
                public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
                    return children[i].length;
                }

                @Override
                public Object getGroup(int i) {
                    return groups[i];
                }

                @Override
                public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
                    return children[i][i1];
                }

                @Override
                public long getGroupId(int i) {
                    return i;
                }

                @Override
                public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
                    return i1;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean hasStableIds() {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
                    TextView textView = new TextView(CategoriesFragment.this.getActivity());
                    textView.setText(getGroup(i).toString());
                    return textView;
                }

                @Override
                public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
                    TextView textView = new TextView(CategoriesFragment.this.getActivity());
                    textView.setText(getChild(i, i1).toString());
                    return textView;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
                    return true;
                }

            }

        Intent k;

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            switch(childPosition){
            case 0:
                k = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Baby.class);
                break;
            case 1:
                k = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Baby1.class);
                break;
            }
            startActivity(k);
            return true;
        }

        }
```

Comment: Is this what you need http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, however still I couldn't make it. How to put condition for each item? Can you provide some further details or may be the code please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in the getChildView function you need to add / remove onClicklistener to textview based on position or data. in that onclicklistener start the activity

Comment: Thanks for your help. However still I couldn't implement it. Please help. I'm new bee to Android development.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on child element what `childposition` you're getting in `OnChildClick` function ??

And where you've set a `ChildClickListener` ?? If you've not set then after this code `ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);`  write this line `elv.setOnChildClickListener("your_listener");`

Also for best practice you can write your above listener and OnChildClick function in this way:

1st remove your OnChildClick and OnChildClickListener (if any) then put your code at the place of above `elv.setOnChildClickListener("your_listener");` this way-

```
elv.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {     
                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                     switch(childPosition){
                        case 0:
                            k = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Baby.class);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            k = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Baby1.class);
                            break;
                        }
                        startActivity(k);
                        return true;
                }           
});
```

Let us know if you're still facing any problem